# AngularJS Datatables insert Table-Footer with column totals

Tags: angularjs, datatables, footer

Do you know how I can easily insert a simple footer (tfoot) into my datatable?
I have build my Datatable in my Angular-Controller like this:

```
function Controller(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $compile) {
   var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.totals = {};

   var initDatatable = function() {
       ctrl.dtInstance = {};

       ctrl.dtColumns = [
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id', 'Id'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('title', 'Name').renderWith(actionsHtml),
    // ... some columns here
       ];

    var renderDatatable = function() {
    ctrl.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
        .newOptions()
        .withFnServerData(serverData)
        .withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
        .withOption('fnFooterCallback', footerCallback);

   function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    }

    function serverData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
    // get data from Server by ajax
    // and then sum the total values
        ctrl.total.col1 += data1;
        ctrl.total.col2 += data2;
        ctrl.total.col3 += data3;

        var records = {
                'draw': draw,
                'recordsTotal': entries.length,
                'recordsFiltered': entries.length,
                'data': entries   // filtered data entries
            };

        fnCallback(records);
    }

    function activateDatatable() {
       initDatatable();
       renderDatatable();
     }
     activateDatatable();
}
```

The Code is compressed by me to see the general structure.
Now I created the function "footerCallback()" to define the table footer, but datatables doesnt generate the `<tfoot>` automatically and because of that I have to create it manually into the template:

```
<table datatable="" dt-instance="ctrl.dtInstance" dt-options="ctrl.dtOptions" dt-columns="ctrl.dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

After a long time of research I find out that I should be generate every th-tag into the footer but I couldn't get my total values from serverData() to insert in the cells.

Could everyone help me?

Comment: If you are creating this footer manually then for table which element are you using? can you elaborate? or paste your table view here

Comment: Hi, the html code above you see is my  (compressed) table view. It beginns with this section-tag:
<section ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">... </section>

Comment: Any solution to this? I am having same issue with it too

Answer (score 0):

i know its an old one, but for completion:

to use the **footerCallback** you have to change this [datatables plugin sum](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()) to angularjs way. (there is a similar way with **drawCallback**)

```
.withOption('footerCallback', function () {
    var api = this.api();
    total = api.column(5).data()
                         .flatten()
                         .reduce( function (a,b) {
                             if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;}
                             if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;}
                             return a + b;
                             }, 0);
    $( api.columns(5).footer() ).html( total );
})
```

you even can use render for the footer, to keep number localization (and currency). for example with the help of the [datatables plugin intl](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/intl)

```
    var renderit = $.fn.dataTable.render.intlNumber('fr', {style: 'currency',currency: 'EUR'} );
    $( api.columns(5).footer() ).html( renderit(total,'display') );
```